# exibir uma imagem através da URL

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de saber se é possível exibir uma imagem em um código HTML onde apenas o link dela está guardado em uma variável em PHP. Eu tentei fazer da forma que achei óbvia mas não obtive sucesso.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php
$imagem = 'http://www.mediafire.com/view/wg0156qxjkzulv3/premium.png/file ';
?>

<img src="<?php echo $imagem;?>" alt="">
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá, Matheus!

O seu código está correto e isso é sim possível. O que está errado é o código da imagem que você utilizou. Se você abrir este link no navegador e clicar com o botão direito em cima da imagem irá aparecer: `Copy Image URL`. É esse URL que você precisa usar. O que você usou é a página toda do mediafire, incluindo botão de compartilhar, login...
Seu código correto ficaria assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php
$imagem = 'http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/c9df/wg0156qxjkzulv3zg.jpg';
?>

<img src="<?php echo $imagem;?>" alt="">
</html>
```